# Getting Scrollviewer to start at the top when reusing in UWP/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I go back into a Scrollviewer it after having used it, it maintains the position I left it at when I closed it.  Is there a way to reset it to the top?

Comment: Did you try this: [MSDN ScrollViewer ScrollToTop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltotop?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ScrollViewer_ScrollToTop)

Comment: That doesn't work in UWP apparently but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If or once you have a reference to the `ScrollViewer` element, you should be able to use its [ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview) method to scroll to the top, e.g.:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(0, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put ((0, 0, null) horizontal, vertical, zoom) and it worked brilliantly, thank you :)